# How to solve this linear first order differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{1}{N}\frac{dN}{dt} + 1 = te^{t+2}$$

The equation is separable and so is easily solvable. However doing so gives me the following:

$$\int \frac{1}{N}dN = \int(te^{t+2} - 1)dt$$

Simplyifing gives:

$$|N| = e^{-t + te^{t+2} - e^{t+2} + c}$$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Why would you need to proceed?  Looks done to me.

Comment: @Mike I want an equation for $N$ which isn't necessarily equal to  the absolute value of $N$.

Comment: @Amzoti I redid the integrals but got the same result - what am I missing?

Comment: $N=\pm$...  That's about all I see.  Integration looks fine from what I can see.

Comment: Yes, the exponential is always positive. But we don't have $\ln n$ on the left side. We have $$\ln |n| = e^{f(t)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps 
$$ \frac{1}{N}\frac{d}{dt}N+1= te^{t+2}$$
$$ \frac{1}{N}\frac{d}{dt}N= te^{t+2}-1$$
$$ \frac{1}{N}dN= te^{t+2}-1\ dt $$
$$ \int \frac{1}{N}dN= \int te^{t+2}-1\ dt $$
$$ \ln|N|+C_1= e^2\int te^t\ dt-\int dt $$
$$ \ln|N|+C_1= e^2 e^t(t-1)+C_2-t+C_3 $$
$$ \ln|N|= e^{t+2}(t-1)-t+C $$
$$ e^{\ln|N|}= e^{e^{t+2}(t-1)-t+C} $$
$$ N= e^{e^{t+2}(t-1)-t+C} $$

Comment: Doesn't $e^{\ln |N|} = |N|$ instead of $N$?

Comment: @guest, have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/511607/161538) question and you'll understand.