# Don't understand how a power of e ends up as a factor in from of e

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

I have a very basic issue that I can't seem to wrap my head around: I am trying to solve the membrane equation
$$\tau \frac{dV(t)}{dt} = -V(t) + E(t)$$
With a time constant $\tau$, the voltage $V(t)$ and an input $E(t) = \alpha t^2$.

And after solving the homogenous version with a constat $E$ via separation of variables countless times, I fail at solving the homogenous part of this one without the $E(t)$.

The solution for $\tau \frac{dV(t)}{dt} = -V(t)$ (based on the solution sheet) is:
$$V(t) = ce^{-t/ \tau}$$
But no matter how I twist it, I always end up with the following
$$V(t) = e^{\frac{-t+c}{\tau}}$$
How do I get the $c$ out of the fraction in the exponent and as a factor of $E$?

Thanks for any help and apologies for the stupid question!

Comment: The solution's $c$ corresponds with your $e^{c/\tau}$. Those are not the same $c$s; it is just a relabeling of an arbitrary constant with another arbitrary constant.

Comment: Your solution can be rewritten as $e^{-\frac{t}{\tau} + \frac{c}{\tau}}= e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} \cdot e^{-\frac{c}{\tau}}$ where the last expression is just a constant. So let's give it a name: $D= e^{-\frac{c}{\tau}}$. Then your solution is $V(t)= De^{-t/\tau}$ which is the same as the solution sheet says

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thank you!

Comment: @Lukas: Actually that only covers the case $D>0$. To obtain the general solution in a correct way, one needs to be more careful, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128769/how-to-simplify-logartihms-with-a-integration-constant) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205538/a-question-regarding-differential-equation). Since the equation here is linear, it's easier to use an integrating factor instead.