# Why negative part should be neglected in first order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question here which ask for $y$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-10x^4y$$
I know how to solve this question using seperation of variables:
$$\int\frac1 y\,dy=-10\int x^4 \,dx$$
$$\ln|y| = -2x^5+C$$
$$|y|=Ce^{-2x^5}$$
$$y=\pm Ce^{-2x^5}$$
But the answer given is just $y=Ce^{-2x^5}$, why the negative part is been thrown away?

Thank you!

Comment: There are lots and lots of similar questions on this site already. See here, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4129002/1242

Comment: And by the way, your first $C$ is not the same as the second $C$, which should have been $e^C$, so that you get $\pm e^C$ at the end (which you rename to $D$, or something; note that $D \neq 0$). And don't forget that the solution $y=0$ must be treated separately (since you divide by $y$ at the beginning); this solution corresponds to $D=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem when writing $\ln|y| = -2x^5+C \implies |y|=Ce^{-2x^5}$ as the two $C$ are not the same number.

First, note that when writing $\ln|y| = -2x^5+C$, we implicitly say that $C$ can be any real number (so many people would write $\ln|y| = -2x^5+C$, with $C\in \mathbb R$) Then, $\ln|y| = -2x^5+C$ is equivalent to $|y|=e^{-2x^5+C}=e^Ce^{-2x^5}=Ae^{-2x^5}$, where $A=e^C$ can be any positive number. This is equivalent to $y=\pm Ae^{-2x^5}=Be^{-2x^5}$, where $B=\pm A$ can be any nonzero real number.

But it should also be noted that, when solving separable equations that way, we assumed $y\neq 0$, so we omitted the equilibrium solution (i.e. constant solution) $y=0$. Therefore, the set of solutions is $y=De^{-2x^5}$, where $D$ is any real number.

Since it is annoying to introduce many variables, many people (me included) would abuse notations by using the same letter as constant and write

$$\ln|y| = -2x^5+C \iff y = Ce^{-2x^5}, C \in \mathbb R$$

---

This can be made rigorous by reminding that, when writing $\int\frac1 y\,dy=-10\int x^4 \,dx \iff  \ln|y| = -2x^5+C$, we omit an existential quantifier and actually mean

$$\int\frac1 y\,dy=-10\int x^4 \,dx \iff  \text{ there exists } C\in\mathbb R\text{ such that } \ln|y| = -2x^5+C$$

which we show above is equivalent to

$$\int\frac1 y\,dy=-10\int x^4 \,dx \iff \text{ there exists } B\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\text{ such that } y = Be^{-2x^5}$$

But since the variable $B$ is a free variable, it can be replaced by any variable, so we can write instead

$$\int\frac1 y\,dy=-10\int x^4 \,dx \iff \text{ there exists } C\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\text{ such that } y = Ce^{-2x^5}$$

Answer (score 3):

Because the constant $C$ in question can be positive or negative anyways, so the $\pm$ is superfluous.

It would be more appropriate to say you're defining a new constant $C'$ such that

$$C' = \begin{cases}
+C & \text{ if you choose the positive} \\
-C & \text{ if you choose the negative} \end{cases}$$

This kind of abuse of notation with arbitrary constants is not uncommon (and not unlike how you let $e^C$ just become $C$ earlier on).

Answer (score 2):

In the process of solving the proposed ODE, you (implicitly) considered that $C > 0$. Due to the modulus behavior, it results that $-C\in\mathbb{R}$ also provides a solution. Finally, if you plug in $y\equiv 0$ in the original equation, you shall conclude that $C = 0$ also corresponds to a solution. In other words, all the solutions can be represented as $y(x) = Ce^{-2x^{5}}$, where $C\in\mathbb{R}$.