# Why can we remove the absolute values in $\left | \frac{y(x)-1}{y(x)} \right | = |x|^K$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is why we can remove the absolute values from equation \eqref{8} below.
In what follows I show the context in which this question arose, namely, solving a differential equation.
Consider the nonlinear separable equation
$$
xy'+y=y^2.\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
We can write it in the forms
$$
xy'=y^2-y\label{2}\tag{2}.
$$
and if $x\neq 0$ we have
$$
y'=\frac{y^2-y}{x}.\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
Now, if $y(y-1)\neq 0$ and $x\neq 0$ then we can write
$$
\frac{y'}{y(y-1)}=\frac{1}{x}.\label{4}\tag{4}
$$
Note that $y=1$ and $y=0$ are solutions to the original equation \eqref{1}.

The remaining solutions, if any exist, must satisfy \eqref{4}.

We have

$$\int \frac{1}{y(x)(y(x)-1)}y'(x)dx=\int\frac{1}{x}dx+K\tag{5}$$

If we make the substitution $z=y(x)$ then $dz=y'(x)dx$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{z(z-1)}dz & =\int\frac{1}{x}dx+K \label{6}\tag{6}\\
\ln{\left | \frac{y-1}{y} \right |} & =\ln{|x|}+K \label{7}\tag{7}\\
\left | \frac{y-1}{y} \right | & = |x|e^K \label{8}\tag{8}\\
\left | \frac{y-1}{y} \right | & = C|x|\label{9}\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
At this point, the book I am following (Apostol, *Calculus Vol. I*, Chapter 8.23 "Separable Equations") says

> This gives us
>
> $$\frac{y-1}{y}=Cx$$
>
> for some constant $C$.

Why can we remove the absolute values?

The term $\frac{y-1}{y}$ is negative in $(0,1)$ and positive elsewhere.

**Here is this entire derivation exactly as it appears in the book for reference**

[image]

Comment: There's a mistake with the substitution. Yes, $dz = y' dx$, but the original integral had $y' dy$.

Comment: @DerekLedbetter Indeed a mistake. However, the mistake was in the original integral (5), which should have $dx$ instead of $dy$ and is now fixed.

Comment: Make sure that you introduce the constant (K) only *after* you do the integration on line 7. Additionally, when you do the inverse of the ln function (exp) you should be careful about exponents. The RHS would be e^k * abs(x) because of the identity e^(x+y) = e^x * e^y. I am adding a duplicate question that shows what to do from here. This could include any number of methods like using a provided initial value or separating the equation out by each interval of interest.

Comment: @AdrianFletcher I believe that when we write indefinite integrals then we can add the constant without solving the integral. The indefinite integral is just another way to express the solved (indefinite) integral.

Comment: @AdrianFletcher Yes that other question does answer my question. However, given that I have cited a specific passage in a specific book, perhaps this question is useful to other people confused with this passage. The author left this entire discussion out.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log\left(\left|\frac{y-1}{y}\right|\right)=\log\left(\left|Cx\right|\right)$$
This turns out to be
$$\frac{y-1}{y}=_{-}^{+}Cx$$
This gives two functions
$$\frac{y-1}{y}=+Cx\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(a\right)$$
and
$$\frac{y-1}{y}=-Cx\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(b\right)$$

The removal of the modulus sign helps define not one, but two functions
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8sdpst2dis
This is the graph for an arbitrary value of C(>0). Notice that the red relation includes all the four curves.
The author probably thought that C can take positive and negative values (or he has deliberately ignored the negative sign for some reason which I cannot comprehend). But I think that the constant(which is k in eqn. (7)) cannot be negative once we write it as a log of another constant (which is C, eqn. (a)).
You can vary the constant (slide over to the negative values) on Desmos to visualize what happens for function (b)

One more thing. Eqn. (8) from your equation seems wrong. you might want to correct that.

[Why does the absolute value disappear when taking $e^{\ln|x|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511607/why-does-the-absolute-value-disappear-when-taking-e-lnx)
Check out this link, particularly the answer by Michael Albanese, for a detailed mathematical approach.

Comment: I have fixed the mistake in equation (8) and also a screenshot of the relevant part in the book with the same derivation.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511607/why-does-the-absolute-value-disappear-when-taking-e-lnx) as suggested in one of the comments, my understanding is the following.

Consider the expression

$$\left |\frac{y-1}{y}\right | = |x|e^c\tag{1}$$

$$\left |\frac{y-1}{y}\right | = k|x|,\ \text{with}\ k>0\tag{2}$$

The sign of the expression $\frac{y-1}{y}$ can be seen from the depiction below

[image]

There are four total cases to consider and they represent the four possible combinations of signs of $\frac{y-1}{y}$ and $x$.

**Case 1:** $x\geq 0$ and $y\in (-\infty,0) \cup (1,\infty)$

$$\frac{y-1}{y}=kx$$

$$y(1-kx)=1$$

and if $x\neq \frac{1}{k}$ then

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{1-kx}$$

Graphically, this looks like

[image]

**Case 2:** $x\leq 0$ and $y\in (0,1)$

In this case, we end up with the same equations as in case 1), except that since $x\leq 0$ we don't have to exclude any values of $x$ since $1-kx\neq 0$ for these values of $x$.

Graphically, what we have is just the portion of the graph of case 1) for $x\leq 0$

[image]

**Case 3:** $x\geq 0$ and $y\in (0,1)$

$$\frac{1-y}{y}=kx$$

$$y(1+kx)=1$$

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{1+kx}$$

[image]

**Case 4:** $x\leq 0$ and $$y\in (-\infty,0) \cup (1,\infty)$

Same equations as in case 3

$$\frac{1-y}{y}=kx$$

$$y(1+kx)=1$$

but $x\neq -\frac{1}{k}$ here

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{1+kx}$$

[image]

So what does all this mean?

In each of the four cases, we obtained a function defined on a certain interval (either $x>0$ or $x<0$, and in two cases with a singularity at 1 and -1, respectively) that satisfies (2) on that interval.

We can create four different functions that solve (2) by combining the functions obtained in the four cases.

So why did the book just go ahead and say that $y=\frac{1}{1-Kx}$ for a general $K\in\mathbb{R}$?

In our calculations, we've been using $k=e^C>0$ and we reached two different expressions $\frac{1}{1-kx}$ and $\frac{1}{1+kx}$ depending on the values of $x$ and $y$ being considered.

The four cases show that we can indeed pick either of these expressions to represent a solution on, respectively, $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{\frac{1}{k}\}$ and $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{-\frac{1}{k}\}$.

Thus we can effectively choose any constant (though depending on the sign the domain is one or the other of the intervals in the previous paragraph).

Thus, we can summarize these two possibilities by writing

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{1-Kx}$$

as the book did. The domain is, apparently, left implicit because it is quiet obvious.